# How to get $_POST data from ajax call of a filter inside the view template?

Tags: views

The wallpaper listing page needs a set of filters which should display the results according to that. The filtered content is loaded using ajax callback using the views in an ajax callback

The loaded results needs to be linked to detail page. The detail page will show a slider with these filtered results in next and previous slider clicks using ajax.The post data array ($_POST) is empty while printing inside the view template.The arguments passed inside the filter needs to be printed in the view template.

Please help me in printing the post data array result in an ajax callback.